# Can't iterate over the elements on and xml file with xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I 've got a xml file with this structure:

```
<profiles>
    <profile profile="SuperAdministrator" name="admin"/>
    <profile project="TesteHandSpy" profile="Researcher" name="john"/>
    <profile project="DunnProject,DAAR1_op,Sara" profile="Researcher" name="juliete"/>
</profiles>
```

And I want to select the project value of profile elements with a certain value for attribute name. I started trying to just list all profile elements and I'm having problems with that. I can find the file but then I use the comands I find in several places and it returns zero results. Here's the xquery I'm testing:

```
let $param := "juliete"
let $profiles:= doc("/db/db_project/profiles.xml")/profiles/profile

for $profile in $profiles
return $profile
```

Can you help me? I guess when this starts to work all I have to do is add [@name=$param] to the query.

Comment: Which processor? Are you sure the path is correct? The xquery you're using is correct to list all profiles.

Comment: @EwoutGraswinckel if I remove the "/profiles/profile" it show the content of my file so I guess that means my path is correct. I also tried to put "//profile" and it didn't work.

Comment: @EwoutGraswinckel I'm trying this on a eXist-db with xquery 3.0

Comment: if your XPath expression isn't selecting any elements, but the document is being returned, it's likely that you have a namespace mismatch. Are there any namespaces (`xmlns="..."`) defined in your document?

Comment: @joemfb yes I have this: xmlns="http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/DAAR/HandSpy" on the <profiles>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a FLOWR expression here.  A simple path would do:

`doc("/db/db_project/profiles.xml")/profiles/profile[@name eq $param]`

The fact that this return nothing can be for several reasons.  The most obvious are 1) the URI is not correct (try calling `doc()` with the same URI to ensure it returns the document) or 2) a namespace problem (you can try `*:profiles/*:profile` to validate that is not the case).

The problem with using `doc()` is that it is not reproducible on someone else's machine.  If you put the content of the document in, say, a variable instead, the query will be self-contained and we will be able to help better.

**Update**

After your comment, it seems it is a namespace problem.  So the XML input you quoted above is not entirely correct.  It lacks some namespace, something like:

```
<profiles xmlns="http://example.org/project">
   ...
</profiles>
```

A path like `/profiles/profile` returns the elements `profile`, children of the element `profiles`, all in NO namespace.  To access those in a specific namespace, you have to bind a prefix to that namespace URI first, and then use the prefix for each element name:

```
declare namespace p = "http://example.org/project";
doc("/db/db_project/profiles.xml")/p:profiles/p:profile[@name eq $param]
```

You have to understand that the prefix used in the query (in this case `p`) and the one used in the XML (in this case no prefix, because the URI is bound as the default namespace) do not have to match.  The URIs they are both bound to have to match.

Comment: Thank you, with *:profiles/*:profile the xquery is working. Can you just explain to me why /profiles/profile doesn't work?